# Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim will be suppressed during this calculation

Tags: recursion, error-handling, suppress-warnings

[code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQjB1.jpg)I can't run the eqs table/matrix of a set of equations solving u[k] like in the attached image and code

```
Nn=2;h=pi/sqrt(Nn)

u[x_] := ([([Sum]), (i = (-Nn)), (Nn)]((u[i]) (cnqff[i]))

delta0[k_, j_] := If[k == j, 1, 0]

delta2[k_, j_] := If[k == j, -[Pi]^2/(3 h^2),(-2(-1)^(j-k))/(h^2(j- k)^2)] 

eqs = Table[1/2[([Sum]), (k =(-Nn)), (Nn)](u[k] delta2[k, j])) + 1/2 
qq[[j]] [([Sum]),(k = (-Nn)),(Nn)](u[k] delta0[k, j])) == [Lambda]([([Sum]), 
(k = (-Nn)),(Nn)](u[k] delta0[k, j])) , {j, -Nn, Nn}]
```

please note that sum is a sigma sign that runs from -Nn to Nn and Nn is set to 2 in this code

Can someone help with this issue?

It sounds silly but before I close the lap yesterday it ran and was executing 3 sparse matrices the 2nd one is the one I'm interested in which was 11 by 9 matrix with column 2 and 11 zeros to be able to extract a 9 by 9 coefficient matrix in order to proceed in my calculations ..

Why did it ran yesterday and today is not .. I've restarted the kernel and the whole sys but unfortunately it didn't run.

Thanks very much in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuVlt.jpg)and Br,